# How to verify @Blocking annotatio is working for quarkus

Tags: quarkus

We are using quarkus framework and https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-reactive mentions that we can use @Blocking on a method, class to instruct Quarkus to invoke this method on a worker thread.

But how exactly can we verify it is using a worker thread?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `io.quarkus.runtime.BlockingOperationControl.isBlockingAllowed()` to see if blocking on the thread is allowed.

If you have used `@Blocking` correctly, the call should return `true`

Comment: Thanks. However this function seems always return true when I call it w/ or w/o @Blocking annotation. Same w/ and w/o returning a Uni or just the plain object.  Seems it's only checking the capability of whether this function can be called on a worker thread?

Comment: Can you update the question with the code you are using?